# Comparing functions asymptotically

Tags: algorithm, math, asymptotic-complexity

I am given two functions: F<sub>1</sub>(n)=2n+20 and F<sub>2</sub>(n)=n+1. I have to show which one is better.

Our lecturer solved a similar problem. Given F<sub>1</sub>(n)=n<sup>2</sup> and F<sub>2</sub>(n)=2n+20, he did:

F<sub>2</sub>(n)/F<sub>1</sub>(n)=(2/n)+(20/n<sup>2</sup>)

and he said it would be always less than 22, hence 2n+20 is better.

My doubt is how do I solve these types of comparison between functions. I have gone through all questions previously asked here and didn't quite understand it.

Also if given (an<sup>2</sup>+bn+c)=O(n<sup>2</sup>), please help in choosing constants c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>0</sub> such that

c<sub>1</sub>g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c<sub>2</sub>g(n).

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate... n^2 is "better" than 2n+20?

Comment: Sorry my mistake Between n^2 and 2n+20 The latter function performs better

Comment: That depends on your definition of *good*. Obviously, `2n+20` is always greater than `n+1` for positive `n`.

Comment: Yes @nico but can you prove that by some mathematical means? I would appreciate it

Comment: Well, the difference `(2n + 20) - (n + 1) = n + 19`. And this difference is obviously positive for all `n > -19`. Therefore, `2n + 20` is greater than `n + 1` for all `n > -19`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in one of the comment, what a *better* complexity is first needs to be defined.

It is likely your lecturer means a complexity `C(n)` *better* than `K(n)` if and only if `C(n) << K(n)` (or using Landau notations `C(n) = o(K(n))`) as `n -> +Inf`.

If you want to compare two complexities `F1(n)` and `F2(n)`, one method is to check if the quotient `F2(n)/F1(n)` converges and if so, to which value. With `F2(n) ~ n` and `F1(n) ~ n^2`, `F2(n)/F1(n)` converges towards `0` and therefore `F1(n)` dominates `F2(n)` towards infinity. You would say `F1(n)` is better given the language convention adopted earlier.

Note that "*it (`F2(n)/F1(n)`) would be always less than 22 and told 2n+20 is better*" is **not** a correct approach to asymptotic analysis in case of domination relationships (`o(.)` or equivalently `<<`)(I doubt your lecturer said that for the `F1(n)` and `F2(n)` defined above.).

In your last question - could you please define `f(n)` and `g(n)` ?